# How to detect whether a bathroom stall is closed?

Tags: arduino, sensor

I've got a bathroom stall with a sliding bolt and would like to detect when the door is closed and locked. I'll receive the state of the door with an Arduino Uno

Not sure what's the best way to go about this, would I use a hall effect sensor?

Comment: Use a magnetic switch.

Comment: Use microswitches

Comment: Depends to some extent on how 'robust' the answer must be. Are 'false positives' acceptable? For example, the door is not quite closed, the sliding bolt is extended, and hence can not slide into the bolt receiver; is it acceptable to wrongly recognise that as a locked door when it is not? Or are 'false negatives' acceptable? For example, the sliding bolt is engaged but not enough to trigger the detector; is it acceptable to wrongly recognise that as open when it is not?

Comment: Why would you want to use electronics to do this? Toilet doors mostly have locking mechanisms, why would you want this detectable by an arduino?

Comment: For the intranet stall availability page of course!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking photointerrupter triggered by the bolt as it crosses into the strike, just at the strike opening so a half-locked bolt still registers as "locked".

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a wet environment is either a IR Reflective sensor ([Example](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Infrared_Reflective_Sensor)) or a hall to be preferred.

And I would recommend the IR solution.